# Round Trip Time of x simultaneous REST requests in steps of y

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, testing, load, jmeter

I have a Tomcat Java EE 6 web application with several REST webservices.

**Requirement:**

I have to test the RTT of requests made to these web services, at various levels of load. Ideally, this will result in a graph looking like the following:

[image]

This is an academic experiment. Therefore I have to generate simultaneous requests in uniform steps: first 10 sim. requests, then 20, 30, 40 ... up to 100. At every step (10, 20, 30 ...) I need an equal number of test results, being a minimum of 30. It is not a requirement to use Apache JMeter.

**What I have tried:**

My test setup consists of two OS X machines, one i7 8GB and one i5 4GB. Typically I run the webapplication on the i5 and let the i7 generate requests.

Using Apache JMeter with the jmeter-plugins I have tried a Stepping Thread Group configuration.

There are two major problems with this approach:

1. The results make no sense once going well above 100 concurrent threads:
   (following graphs depict results from REST GET requests to localhost:8080, the standard Tomcat welcome page - this to make sure my own webapplication is not the cause of funky results)
   [image]
   [image]
   Exporting data and running it through a pivot table into charts in Excel does not result in better graphs.
2. There's no way to set how many times every 'step' (see 30 or more) has to be run EXACTLY.

I have been trying several combinations of server and client machines, network situations and JMeter tests plans for weeks now and I'm at the end of my wits. I'm looking forward to learning how I can properly load-test these REST web services in an academic fashion.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you want to do, try asking your question on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-fr. Also show you JMeter Test plan overview if possible

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I eventually gave up on using JMeter and wrote my own small Java program instead.